# PHP MYSQL: 1st column as a header, second and third column as rows

Tags: php, mysql

How do I made the column, teamname, as a header for my rows. For example, I would like to output this result using PHP:

********* Sandstorm 2:**

```
summonername2
summoner 1
summoner 2
summoner 3
summoner 4
```

**Team #5**

```
Summoner 1
Summoner 1
```

Here is the code that I have in PHP. So far, its outputting unexpected results.

```
$query = "SELECT players.id, team.teamname, players.summonername 
        from team
        INNER JOIN players ON players.team = team.id
        WHERE team.tourneyid = {$id}";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if($i == 0) {
                $heading .= "<h3>". $row['teamname'] ."</h3><table class='table'><tr><th>Summonername</th><th>rank</th></tr>";
            }// team header
            $teams .= "{$heading}<tr><td>". $row['summonername'] ."</td><td>rank</td></tr>";
            $i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could also use the `team name` as your key for gathering all values inside grouping them.

After you have gathered them, then present them accordingly:

```
$query = "
    SELECT players.id, team.teamname, players.summonername 
        FROM team
        INNER JOIN players ON players.team = team.id
        WHERE team.tourneyid = {$id}
";

$teams = array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $team_name = $row['teamname'];
    $summoner_name = $row['summonername'];
    $teams[$team_name][] = $summoner_name; // continually push same team names under a container
}

// then for presentation
foreach($teams as $team_name => $summoners) {
    echo "<h3>{$team_name}</h3><br/>";
    foreach($summoners as $summoner) {
        echo "<p>{$summoner}</p><br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to call the summoner's ID in the $summoner loop? How can this be done?

Comment: @PlusOne you'll just tweak it a bit, instead of pushing just the `summoner name` only inside the gathering `while` loop, you can just push the whole `$row` itself, then you'll get yourself a grouped row array instead of just name, then inside the `foreach` instead of just `$summoner`, now its going to be like: `echo $summoner['id']`, etc.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but how do I include the team ID (which is in the same row as teamname) onto the first loop. I have tried various methods and I've been a lot of invalid results.

Comment: @PlusOne something like this http://pastebin.com/bdGF585n just modify it a bit haven't had the time to test i'm at work

Comment: http://pastebin.com/apc8QdKf I wanted to include like another ID for the teams. This was my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the heading for each row. You probably need to keep track of both the current and the last row, see if the team has changed from the last row to the current, and only print the head in that car. P